# Is the Connoisseur achievement broken?

Tags: achievements, turbo-dismount

The criteria for the Connoisseur achievement in Turbo Dismount is this:

*Try everything once.*

I could have sworn I did. I've gotten rid of the exclamation marks on each vehicle, character and default level, but the achievement still has not showed up.

**Is the achievement broken, or have I just done it wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the achievement while doing following:

- I tried all default tracks/levels;
- I tried all vehicles;
- I tried all characters;
- I tried all poses for 1 character (you don't have to try all poses for all
  characters and maybe the poses aren't important at all)

So, you didn't try all levels...and maybe not all poses for 1 character?

Comment: First off, signatures aren't appreciated here on this site. Second, by trying, do you mean carrying out a run with each of them or just switching to them and then switching again?

Comment: I carried at least 1 run with each of them, so I didn't just switch over and over again. Some say this requires a lot of time, but I didn't experience that; but I really enjoy(ed) the game and almost got this achievement automatically. I only had to choose different characters, sticking to Mr. Dismount most of the time due to the 'Disintegration' achievement. Let me know if this worked :)

Comment: Fine. Once I get back from where I'm staying for a few days, I'll try out the solution you gave and mark your answer as accepted if it works for me. I hope you have a great time on StackExchange, anway.

Comment: That's fine too! Btw: you never experience any problems with your internet connection? I remember missing an achievement for the game Super Meat Boy, because I lost connection and the achievement didn't register. I then had to play the required levels again to get the achievement. Thanks for the words.

Comment: I thought so! Nice :) Now get the remaining achievements...if you want and have to of course. You're welcome!